# INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE Error when I ran the 'npm run android' command

Tags: android, react-native

I am new to Android development and I opted for [React Native](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)#React_Native) instead of native. When I run `npm run android`, I am getting the following error:

```
com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE

at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installRemotePackage(Device.java:1133)
at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackage(Device.java:963)
at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackage(Device.java:939)
at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackage(Device.java:928)
at com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.installPackage(ConnectedDevice.java:126)
```

What does this mean, and how can I fix it?

I am using Android Studio 3.6.3.

[image]

Comment: Thanks chris. App: install part  threw this error,, Issue got fixed after wiping the data from the emulator.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your device does not have enough space. Try making space by removing unwanted files on your device (emulator or phone).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68599636/3201843 is a much better answer with a practical solution.

Comment: For a real device (not emulator), how do you tell what file system it is running out of space on??

Comment: @Ribo in your phone settings, you can search for Analyze Storage, there it shows which all the files are duplicate and which all files are taking more space.

Answer (score 120):

It means that the device you're running it on (an emulator in my case) is running low on internal (in most cases) or external storage.

To increase the emulator's space follow the following steps (refer to GIF for exact directions):

1. In Android studio, go to *AVD Manager*, and for your specific emulator go for *down arrow button*  & select '**Edit**'
2. Scroll down & click on '**Show Advanced Settings**'
3. Scroll down to *Memory and Storage* section
4. Increase (or decrease) the *Internal Storage* to the desired value

[image: increase emulator space]

Comment: On a real device (not emulator) it was the /data filesystem that was low on space.  Do an:  adb shell df     -- and see if the free space in /data is low.

Comment: Gracias, esto sirve

Answer (score 11):

I had an older version of my app installed.
I uninstalled it from the phone, and re-install the app (via the react-native `run-android` command) and it worked.

Comment: This was the solution for me. There wasn't a shortage of space at all, but uninstalling the app from the emulator made the INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE go away.

Answer (score 6):

Clear your emulator/ phone memory, where you are installing

Comment: Thanks wiped our the data in android studio and it is working like a charm.

Step: Tools -> AVD Manager -> Select Emulator -> Wipe data

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your project using:

```
npx react-native run-android
```

Or wipe the data from emulator options. This will delete all extra apps from your device giving you some extra memory.

[image]

or

```
cd android
./gradlew uninstallAll
```

to uninstall any app instance in your emulator device.

Answer (score 0):

I had to update my SDK platform version. Nothing else had worked for me.

Inside SDK Manager, there was an update available for [Android 12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_12) (S) → Google APIs ARM 64 v8a System Image.